# Trying to return first instance of word in listview from specified line index

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, function, listview

Like the title says I am trying to return the first instance of a word in a listview from a specified index. So this means it would not search from the beginning of the listview it would actually return from whichever line I have added into the parameters. I can't seem to get it to work, I can get it to work with the selected item but not with a variable input into the parameters.

```
    Private Function FindLogic(ByVal LV As ListView, ByVal CIndex As Integer, ByVal SearchFor As String) As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim It = From i In LV.Items Where i.index > LV.Items(CIndex).Index And i.Text = SearchFor
    If It.Count > 0 Then
        idx = It(0).Index
    Else
        idx = -1
    End If
    Return idx
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your query: you're missing the Select part, for one. This seems to do the trick:

```
Dim It As List(Of ListViewItem)
It = (From i As ListViewItem In lvwMain.Items Where i.Index > CIndex And i.Text = SearchFor Select i).ToList
```

I'm assuming CIndex is the index of the ListView item where you want to start the search. If so, there is no need for a lookup of that item just to get its index value (it will just be the same as CIndex).

Comment: Thanks Chris it is working properly, but how could I change it so I could find the word in a specific column of the listview and not just the first on? I have two column and I keep getting -1 results so I am geussing it has to do with searching the wrong column.

Comment: To check an arbitrary column, you would need to compare SearchFor with i.SubItems(indexOfSomeColumn).Text. The index values for all columns after the first start with 1. You could also use a string key to find the subitem, but only if you gave it a name when you initially added it to the ListView. Also, if you just want to know if a given word is present in any part of a column value, you can use the Contains() methods of the string class.